# extract fields from bib bibliographic file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I want to extract specific fields from a natbib/bibtex bibliographic file to construct a table similar to:

```
title
-------------------------------------------------
authors
-------------------------------------------------
journal, year, volume
-------------------------------------------------
abstract
-------------------------------------------------
```

is there a way to do this in latex?

Thanks
Jorge

Comment: Would `biblatex` an option for you? With that it would be pretty easy.

Comment: yes, it would, as long as it does not cause issues to the rest of the citations in the text (never used biblatex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `biblatex` it is easy to cite a specific field using `\citefield{<citation>}{<field>}`. Some of the fields have also dedicated commands, for example `\citeyear`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@article{citation,
  title     = {title},
  author    = {author},
  journal   = {journal},
  pages     = {1--8},
  year      = 2006,
  month     = jan,
  abstract  = {bla bla bla},
  volume    = {3},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{citation}

\citetitle{citation}

\citeyear{citation}

\citeauthor{citation}

\citefield{citation}{journaltitle}

\citefield{citation}{abstract}

\citefield{citation}{volume}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]